# Getting [object Promise] error when using slc loopback:relation

Tags: mongodb

I am getting [object Promise] error whenever I try to add a relation between 2 models. Please see the below snippet.

C:\sairam\OMSaiRamC\FullStack\Session - 5\Week 4\loopback-server>slc loopback:model
? Enter the model name: Test2
? Select the data-source to attach undefined to: MongoDB (mongodb)
? Select model's base class PersistedModel
? Expose Test2 via the REST API? Yes
? Custom plural form (used to build REST URL):
? Common model or server only? common
Let's add some Test2 properties now.

Enter an empty property name when done.
? Property name: Price
   invoke   loopback:property
? Property type: string
? Required? Yes
? Default value[leave blank for none]:

Let's add another Test2 property.
Enter an empty property name when done.
? Property name: Label
   invoke   loopback:property
? Property type: string
? Required? Yes
? Default value[leave blank for none]:

Let's add another Test2 property.
Enter an empty property name when done.
? Property name:

C:\sairam\OMSaiRamC\FullStack\Session - 5\Week 4\loopback-server>slc loopback:relation
? Select the model to create the relationship from: Test1
? Relation type: has many
? Choose a model to create a relationship with: Test2
? Enter the property name for the relation: (test2s)

> > [object Promise]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. Strongloop acknowledged this as a bug in their latest version of generator-loopback npm module.  So the issue is resoled.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Loopback and solve that problem

```
sudo npm install -g strongloop
```